# How to integrate Jupyter notebook scala kernel with apache spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-scala

I have installed Scala kernel based on this doc: https://github.com/jupyter-scala/jupyter-scala
Kernel is there:

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python3     /usr/local/homebrew/Cellar/python3/3.6.4_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel/resources
  scala       /Users/bobyfarell/Library/Jupyter/kernels/scala
```

When I try to use Spark in the notebook I get this:

```
val sparkHome = "/opt/spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7"
val scalaVersion = scala.util.Properties.versionNumberString
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline

Compilation Failed
Main.scala:57: object apache is not a member of package org
 ; import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
              ^
```

I tried:

- Setting SPARK_HOME and CLASSPATH to the location of $SPARK_HOME/jars
- Setting -cp option pointing to $SPARK_HOME/jars in kernel.json
- Setting classpath.add call before imports

None of these helped. Please note I don't want to use Toree, I want to use standalone spark and Scala kernel with Jupyter. A similar issue is reported here too: https://github.com/jupyter-scala/jupyter-scala/issues/63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are following the jupyter-scala [directions for using Spark](https://github.com/jupyter-scala/jupyter-scala#spark).  You have to load spark into the kernel using the special imports.